# Delegate method not invoked

Tags: swift, delegates

Guys I have a problem with invoking a delegate method in a view controller. I followed several tutorials but I'm not able to get it working. Can you point what I am doing wrong? Thanks

View:

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func showNutrients(cell: TableViewCell)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nutrientsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var removeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealLabel: UILabel!

    weak var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func showNutrients(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.showNutrients(cell: self)
    }

}
```

View Controller:

```
class NutritionViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, TableViewCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var cell = TableViewCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        cell.delegate = self
    }

    ...

    func showNutrients(cell: TableViewCell) {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        self.meals[indexPath!.row].nutrientsShown.negate()
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .none)
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a cell like `var cell = TableViewCell()`, what you should do is dequeue the cell in `cellForRowAt`, then set the delegate, i.e. `cell.delegate = self.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did that but the method is still not being invoked.

Comment: Oh now it works, I did set the delegate first and dequeued the cell after that. All I had to do was reverse those 2 lines. Stupid mistake. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: No problem, I added this as an answer, feel free to accept it if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating a cell like `var cell = TableViewCell()`, what you should do is dequeue the cell in `cellForRowAt`, then set the delegate, i.e. `cell.delegate = self`.